# Prevent page reloading continuously

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using `window.history.pushState({)` inside a function. This works fine as expected. Below is a an example.

```
$('#go_btn').click(function(){
   if ($('.green')) {
        var newurl = "cutomurl.html";
        if(newurl!=window.location){
             window.history.pushState({path:newurl},'',newurl);
        }
        return false;
   }
});
```

and I've also got the below code to be able to refresh the page when the `newurl` is being triggered by the `$('#go_btn')` button.

```
$(window).on('popstate', function(){ 
    location.reload(true); 
});
```

On the desktop version I don't seem to have any issues. But when I try to load this page on my iPad it continuously keeps on reloading the page over an over again. So how do I stop the continuous reloading and make the page refresh only when `window.history.pushState({path:newurl},'',newurl);` is being triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note that just calling history.pushState() or history.replaceState()
>   won't trigger a popstate event. The popstate event is only triggered
>   by doing a browser action such as clicking on the back button (or
>   calling history.back() in JavaScript). And the event is only triggered
>   when the user navigates between two history entries for the same
>   document.
>
> Browsers tend to handle the popstate event differently on page load.
>   **Chrome (prior to v34) and Safari always emit a popstate event on page
>   load, but Firefox doesn't**.
>   *According to Mozzila Developer Network*
>   *https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate*

Safari always emit a popstate event on page load. It means that

1. Your page loads
2. Popstate event occurs
3. location.reload() executes
4. It is repeating

**Update**: 
Please, read a documentation about manipulation the browser history.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

It looks like you misunderstand some functionality.

You have a #go_btn button. When you click it, you want a page to:

### 1. Reload

Use `location.reload()`

```
if (newurl != window.location)
{
    // window.history.pushState({path:newurl},'',newurl);
    location.reload(true);
}
```

### 2. Navigate to a new URL

Use `location.href`. It will **open new page in a current window**.

```
if (newurl != window.location)
{
    // window.history.pushState({path:newurl},'',newurl);
    location.href = newurl;
}
```

### 3. Change the URL in browser history and address bar without doing anything.

Use `window.history.pushState()` or `window.history.replaceState()`. 
It doesn't open a new page or reloads it. It is only used when you are not going to navigate but want user to get new URL (for convenient browsing, history or favorites).

```
if (newurl!=window.location)
{
    window.history.pushState({path:newurl},'',newurl);
}
```

In all of there three cases you don't need `popstate` event. It is used for other purposes.

Which one do you need? It's up to your task.
Anyway, using any two of them together is not illogical and useless. What is the reason of pushing the history state if you are going to refresh the page? Navigate to it then.

Comment: thanks. Are you saying that I can not refresh the page when the `pushState` is triggered?

Comment: @Becky Nope. I am saying that you cannot reload page in `popstate` event because it occurs on page load in Chrome and Safari. Everything is ok about first part of yoru code.

Comment: What are the options that can be used to replace `popState` ?

Comment: @Becky Actually, I couldn't understand why do you want to reload a page on `popstate`. "To be able to refresh the page when the newurl is being triggered by the $('#go_btn') button". As mentioned above, `history.pushState()` and `history.replaceState()` **do not** trigger `onpopstate` event. What is the reason of using it? Is there a need in refreshing? If you want to "reload" a page with a new url then you don't need it. `history.pushState()` and `history.replaceState()` are designed to replace URL in browser history, not loading new page!

Comment: Yes, there is a reason for reloading the page when `$('#go_btn')` is clicked and when the IF statement is true.